# Excel Formula with blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

New user,  I"m multiplying two columns, I17*K17 with answer in L17.  Sometimes cells in column K are blank, when this happens then I need the value of I17 placed in L17.

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula:

```
=I17*IF(K17="",1,K17)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving is by using `ISEMPTY` together with `IF`

Sample Data

```
   I K L
16 4 2 8
17 1 2 2
18 3   3
```

Formula for column L

```
=IF(ISEMPTY($K17);$I17;$I17*$K17)
```